# Calling ASP.Net Web API From ASP.NET Website Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

For the last couple of hours i'm trying to execute `web api action` hosted in `asp.net webforms website`.
I know its wired but due to old project design i have to do this.each time i call the action in `Controller` i got

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3049/api/chart/test?id=58'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Chart' that matches the request."}
```

My Project structure as follows:-

[image: project structure]

My Classes code looks very simple:-

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        }
    }
```

My Controller:-

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ChartController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public static string test(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

What i miss ?

Comment: I've never seen a `static` controller method like that.  Shouldn't it be an instance method?  Also, the route mapping doesn't seem to imply the use of action names in the routes.  Depending on the version of WebAPI, you might need to simply name the method `Get` instead of `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your action method non-static. In Microsoft's documentation, they say this:

> Which methods on the controller are considered "actions"? When selecting an action, the framework only looks at public instance methods on the controller.

Also, your routing is in the form of `api/{controller}/{id}` but the URL you're accessing is in the form of `/api/controller/action?id=string`. Notice the mismatch? You can change your action method to match your route.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(string id)
{
    return id;
}
```

And then access it at `/api/chart/58`.

With the default routing structure in Web API, your route tells it what controller, the selected action method is based on the HTTP Method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH) and the parameters, and then other segments of the URL become the parameters.

Learn more detail about [Web API Routing on MSDN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection).